# How to add custom validation function in Dynamic model in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I am using dynamic model in my yii2 basic application.

following is code of my dynamic model.

```
$model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
        'role', 'from_rm', 'to_rm', 'user1_subdistrcts'
    ]);
    $model->addRule(['user1_subdistrcts', 'role'], 'required', ['message' => "Please select this field."])
->addRule(['from_rm'], 'checkRm');
```

here i am willing to user custom validation function 'checkRm' form `from_rm` field i have also defined checkRm function like this :

```
public function checkRm($from_rm, $params)
{
    $this->addError($from_rm, 'Please Select Regional Manager.');
}
```

But when i submit form i get error Class checkRm does not found

Now please help how to use custom validation in dynamic model.

I have also tried `when` and `whenClient` conditions but those are also not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
    'role', 'from_rm', 'to_rm', 'user1_subdistrcts'
]);
$model->addRule('from_rm', function ($attribute, $params) use ($model) {
    $model->addError($attribute, 'Please Select Regional Manager.');
});
```

**EDIT:**

Yes, it works. But if you want to test with an empty value for `from_rm`, you need to set `skipOnEmpty` to `false`. Example:

```
    $model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
        'role', 'from_rm', 'to_rm', 'user1_subdistrcts'
    ]);
    $model->addRule('from_rm', function ($attribute, $params) use ($model) {
        $model->addError($attribute, 'Please Select Regional Manager.');
    }, [
        'skipOnEmpty' => false,
    ]);

    $model->validate();
    var_dump($model->getErrors());
```

Comment: Hi mat0ng thanks for your answer.. but it is also not working for me.. have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

This works if `checkRm` is a method of `DynamicModel` class. So either extend `DynamicModel` and add this method or use closure like:

```
...->addRule(['from_rm'], function ($attribute, $params) {
    $this->addError($from_rm, 'Please Select Regional Manager.');
});
```